# Overlap a picture with login field - not responsive

Tags: html, css, overlap, responsive

I have a big picture for my header and I want to have a login field in the corner. I used position: relative on the photo, and then position: absolute on the login field to manually put it in the corner (top and right in CSS). The problem is the "right" attribute seems to correspond to window size, so as I narrow my browser, it stays a fixed distance from the side of the browser, pushing it out of the corner of the photo.

[image]

The second image shows what it's supposed to look like, the first shows how it gets shifted.

Here's my HTML code:

```css
#header {
  width: 1100px;
}
#logo {
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  width: 1100px;
}
#logo img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#login {
  top: 317px;
  right: 166px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 220px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="Images/logolow.jpeg, Images/logo.jpg 2x">
        <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="Images/logolowvert.jpeg, Images/logovert.jpeg 2x">
          <img src="Images/logolow.jpeg" srcset="Images/logo.jpg 2x" alt="Prof Pro Logo">
    </picture>
  </div>
  <div id="login">
    <fieldset>
      <Legend>Login</Legend>
      Username
      <input type="text" name="username" />Password
      <input type="password" name="password" />
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
      <a href="Assignment 1 - Register.html">
        <div id="register">
          Not a member? Click here to register!</a>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the `#login` to stay with `position:absolute` relative to another div, that other div must be his parent . in your HTML structure `#logo` and `#login` are siblings. so `#login` with `position:absolute`, will never stay relative to `#logo`. instead use `position:relative` on `#header` .

and add `{ right:0}` so the `#login` will always stay on the right edge of `#header`

if you want to use distances relative to the window width, use `vw` , for example the value of `{ right:5vw }` will dynamically change with the window width ( viewport width )

dont;t forget to write `#` before `header` because as i can see in your css , the `#` is not present.

```css
#header {
    width: 1100px;
    position:relative;
}

#logo {
    
    height: 450px;
    width: 1100px;
} 

#logo img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#login {
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 220px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="Images/logolow.jpeg, Images/logo.jpg 2x">
                    <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="Images/logolowvert.jpeg, Images/logovert.jpeg 2x">
                    <img src="Images/logolow.jpeg" srcset="Images/logo.jpg 2x" alt="Prof Pro Logo">
                </picture>
            </div>  
            <div id="login">
                    <fieldset>
                    <Legend>Login</Legend>
                    Username <input type="text" name="username"/>
                    Password <input type="password" name="password"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                    <a href="Assignment 1 - Register.html">
                    <div id="register">
                        Not a member? Click here to register!
                    </div>
                    </a>
                    </fieldset>     
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set your style for `#header` to `position: relative;`, instead of `#logo`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the login box to always be against the right side of the page regardless of browser size

change your css for the login id

```
#login {
  position:absolute;
  top:317px;
  right:0px;
}
```